# Change default text for "Previous" and "Next" variables

Tags: html, css, e-commerce, bigcartel

The default text for the "previous" and "next" variables that BigCartel has set, look like: "**« Previous**" and "**Next »**", how would I change these to whatever I want them to say if the code is a variable? (Looks like this below):

```
{% if paginate.previous.is_link or paginate.next.is_link %}
{{ paginate | default_pagination }}
{% endif %}
{% else %}
<p class="alert-noproducts">No products found.</p>
{% endif %}

{% endpaginate %}
```

**And here's the site I'm working on, if need be:**

http://shopmoonfall.bigcartel.com/products

Answer (score 0):

You can use ["replace"](http://help.bigcartel.com/customer/portal/articles/772749-filters#string) to edit that variable, for example:

Replace `{{ paginate | default_pagination }}` in the Products page with:

`{{ paginate | default_pagination | replace: "Next &raquo;", "New Text Here" | replace: "&laquo; Previous", "New Text Here" }}`

Answer (score 0):

```
{{ paginate | default_pagination: "id", "class", "previous", "next"}}
```